# Can I use (EJS or Pug) with Angular? or Angular already comes with a default templating engine?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Does Angular already come with a templating engine?

If I wish to work with MEAN stack then is it valid to use EJS or Pug as a templating engine? If yes then how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can use `Interpolation` which refers to embedded expression in the markup text. To use `interpolation` you need to use double-curly braces like `{{}}` for example:

```
<h1>CustomerName: {{ name }} </h1>
```

you can also use `Template Expression` which produce a value and also appears in double-curly-braces.

But besides this you can use Nodejs, Expressjs's  `template-engine` like `ejs`, `pug` and `handlebars` will help you to create dynamic content. You can choose any one of them. For example, in order to use `ejs` you need to install it first. You can write below command in your terminal

```
npm i ejs
```

and import it in your root file

```
const ejs = require ('ejs');
```

and then you need to setup view engine like

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then you need to save all your `views` file in `.ejs` extension

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
  res.render('index', { name: 'Hello' });
});

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running'));
```

Now You can access value of the name in your `ejs` file dynamically like

```
<%=name %>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am currently using ejs with node+express, how can I make my current project environment with angular?

Comment: Do you want to use `Angular` or `templating-engine`?  If you are using `ejs` then why do you need to use `Angular'? Though `Angular` is `framework` both `angular` and `ejs` helps you to develop `views` or `front-end` to the users.